# Peculiarities about Finding Absolute Values

Tags: absolute-value

It is known that the formula $\sqrt{x^2}$ is equal to the value of $|x|$.  In my spare time last night, I wondered about $\sqrt[3]{x^3}$.  After some thought and some graphing, I came up with this:

---

> If $x<0$, $\Im(\sqrt[3]{x^3})$
>
> If $x=0$, $0$
>
> If $x>0$, $\Re(\sqrt[3]{x^3})$

---

This system is equal to $|x|$.

Why is this?

Comment: This isn't equal to $|x|$. $\sqrt[3]{x^3} = x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Its imaginary part is $0$ for every real $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But you're wrong: For $x\in \mathbb R$, $$\sqrt[3]{x^3} = x$$ plain and simple.

Take a simple example: $$\sqrt[3]{(-1)^3} = -1 \neq |-1| = 1$$

Comment: Oops.  This is what happens to late night breakthroughs.

Comment: I know the feeling! ;-)

Comment: Who doesn't, @amWhy ? +1

Comment: @DonAntonio ;) Your comments always make my day!

Comment: @amWhy: Clear --->> +1

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[3]{x^3}$ is not equal to $|x|$. For this, consider the following examples:

- if $x=\color{red}{+}2$ then $x^3=(\color{red}{+}2)^3=\color{red}{+}8$.
- if $x=\color{red}{-}2$ then $x^3=(\color{red}{-}2)^3=\color{red}{-}8$.

So $$\sqrt[3]{\color{red}{+}8}=\color{red}{+}2$$ but $$\sqrt[3]{\color{red}{-}8}=\color{red}{-}2$$ We have these facts while $(\pm2)^2=4$ and so $\sqrt{4}$ is just $+2$ because $\sqrt{...}$ cannot accept any negative number inside when working with reals.

Comment: Nice, sharp and short. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks Sir Don Antonio. ;-)

Comment: I agree with Sir Don Antonio! +1

Answer (score 1):

Under standard conventions, $\sqrt[3]{x}=x$ for all real $x$, which you can easily show. It gets much trickier if you're working in complex numbers.